# How to change only color of text in tabhost in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to write style for this. I am facing problem of how to get Text Color in style.

Answer (score 2):

It's something very basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <style name="text">
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); // unselected
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))

    }
});
```

To set text color initially in your activity, you can use this code in onResume() function

```
TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```